# how can i fix my split function for data cleaning

Tags: c#, data-cleaning

I have a CSV file where there is a column of data set as:
(WIFI; Roku; Large Driveway)

I want to split these into two separate strings to normalize it and have been using the split function but it doesn't seem to be working correctly as I get the original input back.

I have tried this set of code but it doesn't seem to be changing anything

```
string cabinextras;

foreach (var extra in line.Extras)
{
    cabinextras = line.Extras.ToString();
    if (cabinextras.Contains(";"))
    {
        cabinextras.Split(";");

    }

}
```

Comment: What's the loop for if you don't use `extra` and do this `cabinextras = line.Extras.ToString();`? Can you make this a [mcve] and show a couple of lines of your input file? `Split` has a return value for a reason, you should consider using it.

Comment: `it doesn't seem to be working correctly as I get the original input back` You should check the documentation as you seem to not be using it correctly